# Sonarqube incorrect report for duplicated code

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I am a newbie to SonarQube and trying to use the tool for measuring my product quality.

In some cases, I  found that the duplicated lines is reported incorrectly by SonarQube . The number of lines of code is less than the duplicated lines. How can that be ? Either the count of lines of code is  incorrect or the count of duplicated lines is incorrect.

Assuming it could be a problem with my code alone, I visited the demo page of Sonarqube https://sonarqube.com/component_measures/domain/Duplications?id=com.adobe%3Aas3corelib

There as well , I found that one of the cases the lines of code is less than duplicated lines.

Where is the issue ?  How do I address it ?

[image: Screenshot of the error from sonar demo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the difference between *Lines* and *Lines of Code*. For instance, how many of each are below:

```
public void foo() {

  int i = 0;

  for (int j=0; j < 10; j++) 

    doTheThing(j);

 }
```

I'd say that's 4 LoC (maybe 5. Don't remember if the '}' counts) but 9 Lines.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I should have seen that earlier

Comment: Hi Ann, I see another scenario where the Lines of code is calculated as zero and duplicated lines is non-zero. How could that be ?

Comment: Check the duplicated blocks markers in the file. That should help you understand